# Creating a Function and Call It

Tags: php, functions

PRE INFORMATION:

I am using Wordpress and Divi.
I am using Child Theme.

I am building product pages with project feature of Wordpress in order to display them to customers. There is no option to display project tags on a project page.

I want to add a function to functions.php of child theme which it calls and lists to tags of project. Then I will call this function on project page with the Code Module.

How I could do this? I have written some codes but they don't work so I don't add them here :)

Comment: What's the project feature of WordPress? I don't have that. Is it from Divi?

Comment: Presumably though this is just a custom post type, though. So you just need to call [wp_get_post_tags()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_tags/) and display the result?